# MySQL user password problem

Tags: mysql, c, ubuntu

A few months ago I developed a program in C which interacts with a MySQL database and is running on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately I forgot the user's password and now whenever I run the program I get:

> Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

That's quite strange since the password is correct and it's the root password which obviously doesn't match the word 'yes'..

How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you login to mysql with the 'root' account? If so you can reset the password for user1.

Comment: 'YES' indicates that a password was used, not the actual password used. Have a look here to reset your root password - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: `using password: YES` just means you're authenticating using a password, not that the password is actually `YES`. It means you are supplying the wrong password.

Comment: Usually posting some relevant code can also help, maybe something there is wrong..

Answer (score 2):

`using password: YES` means that you tryied to login using a password (not that you used the password `YES`)

Try changing the user's password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new password') WHERE Name = 'user1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to login as `root` (or as another user with sufficient permissions) and then change the password for user `user1`. You have a few options to alter password (using `SET PASSWORD`, using `GRANT`, or issuing update query against `mysql.user`). Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) 
for examples.